# Equivalent of python's __iter__ in R6 classes in R

Tags: r

I want to make objects of my R6 class iterable with a for loop in R like:

```
for (element in object) {
    print(element)
}
```

where `object` is an instance of my class.  In python I would implement the `__iter__` function on my class.  Same with `__len__` for `len(object)` to work properly.  Is there an analogous way to implement these in R?

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
# create your refclass
bar <- setRefClass("foo", fields = list(name="character",len = "numeric"))
# set generics for `[` and `length`
setMethod("[", c("foo","numeric"), function(x, i,drop) { sprintf("%s:%s",x$name,i) })
setMethod("length", c("foo"), function(x ) { x$len })
```

and then iterate like so:

```
one <- bar$new(name="hi",len = 5)
for(i in seq_along(one)) cat(one[i],"\n")

#> "hi:1"
#> "hi:2"
#> "hi:3"
#> "hi:4"
#> "hi:5"
```

If you wanted a more stateful, you could use the `iterators` packages and implement an iterator function `nextElem` method:

```
setMethod("nextElem", c("foo"), function(obj) { ... })
```